# Prefab not instantiating in the next scene Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, scene

I have a problem with bullet prefab in next scene. In first scene the bullet is instantiated and shoots, but in other scenes the same bullet prefab is not instantiated for some reason. A picture of the situation is below.

First, I reckoned it was due to because the Biker was a regular GameObject in the scene and not a prefab like everything else in my scene. Initially I had a new separate Biker gameobject in each scene. Then I made a prefab out of the Biker too, but still the bullet it should shoot is not instantiated. Everything else in the scene - like text labels, the player sprite itself and the gun - are displayed, just the bullet is not instantiated when i hit the space bar.

However, after making the player (Biker) a prefab, it still doesn't work. I debugged, and saw that in the first scene the the method Shoot() is being called and the BulletTrailPrefab is instantiated, but as soon as I get to the second scene (using SceneManager) the Unity console doesn't change and doesn't add any new print() messages, so I assume that the Shoot() code never gets loaded in the next scene.

Any ideas? I would appreciate it very much if you could give some hints and tips as to what could possibly be the problem:)

```cs
void Shoot()
{
    print("NEW BULLETTRAIL INSTANTIATED: " + BulletTrailPrefab);
    if (BulletTrailPrefab != null)
    {
        Transform trail = Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, 
        firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
        LineRenderer lr = trail.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (lr != null)
        {
            lr.SetPosition(0, firePoint.position);
            lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(0, 40, 0));
        }

        Destroy(trail.gameObject, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwordRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform BulletTrailPrefab;
    public Transform BulletParticlePrefab;
}
```

```cs
public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        //...
        Invoke("LoadNextScene", 6f);
    }

    void LoadNextScene()
    {
        activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
       
        if (activeScene.buildIndex == 2)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNameToLoad);
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: We'll need to see a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example to help you debug this. That means a reader should be able to create a new project and reproduce this problem using only the code and prefab/scene setup instructions in your question. If your problem only happens on scene load, we should have the code that loads the new scene, as well as details about how to set up that scene. If your code involves a variable, we should see the declaration of that variable and how it's been assigned a value. And so on.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out shortcomings in my original post. I tried to fix them as much as I found reasonable. I believe I've posted sufficient amount information. My hope is, that if there's something very obvious I'm making wrong in my code, or if someone has encountered a similar situation, then they would be able to point that out. Thanks for any opinion, and kind regards:)

Comment: What is calling shoot?where is it? A function on your player? Something in the scene? Are you calling it periodically, as an action or on key?

Comment: @Zibelas I guess it's not obvious from the looks of it, but yes, the Shoot() function is on the player prefab. And it is called on every space key press. I suspect the problem might be something to do with scene change not reloading the shooting script, although the player prefab is displayed in the scene. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DMGregory You seem a knowledgeable and helping person. Would you have any intuition or hunch on the issue? Surely, that would help out others here as well if we could find a solution to the scene switch and prefab persistence thing.

Comment: If it is on the player, have you made sure that the new scene contains the eventsystem as well?

Comment: Still waiting for that Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. From your shared code, we can't see what class `Shoot()` is in. From your shared screenshots, we can't see where the BulletTrail (Transform) reference is pointing to (eg. a scene asset or a prefab).

Comment: The problem was that I had a conditional check if endOfGame == false, only then Shoot(). That worked for single scenes. However, when you have multiple scenes, you can't have the next scene's endOfGame == true, because then it wouldn't shoot the bullets anymore. Always use your IDE's degubber tools!:)